# SWT application on Mac OS X does not close when typing Cmd-W

Tags: java, macos, swt

I am writing an SWT application on Mac OS X 10.10.1.

Usually, a window is closed if I type <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd>, and the application is terminated if I type <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd>. However <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> shortcut does not work on my SWT application(<kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd> is working).

Do I need to write some key event handler for <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> or something by myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to use a key listener to deal with this.

Since you want to handle the key regardless of which control has focus you probably want to use `Display.addFilter` to deal with the event:

```
Display display = ... your display

Listener keyListener = new KeyListener();

display.addFilter(SWT.KeyDown, keyListener);


class KeyListener implements Listener
{
  @Override
  public void handleEvent(final Event event)
  {
    if (event.stateMask == SWT.COMMAND && event.keyCode == 'w')
     {
       ... close the window
     }
  }
}
```

You also need to use `Display.removeFilter` when the window is closed to stop using this listener.